# AST eclipse, trying to create an InfixExpression

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree

I am working on an Eclipse code formatting plugin using the AST.

I am trying to create an InfixExpression using this code:

```
public static InfixExpression makeInfixExpression(final AST t, final ASTRewrite r, final InfixExpression.Operator o,
        final Expression left, final Expression right) {
    final InfixExpression $ = t.newInfixExpression();
    $.setOperator(o);
    $.setRightOperand(right.getParent() == null ? right : (Expression) r.createMoveTarget(right));
    $.setLeftOperand(left.getParent() == null ? left : (Expression) r.createMoveTarget(left));
    return $;
}
```

with this command:

```
makeInfixExpression(t, r, InfixExpression.Operator.PLUS, asgnThen.getRightHandSide(), otherAsgn)
```

Declarations:

```
final Assignment asgnThen, final Expression otherAsgn;
```

But the InfixExpression I am getting back from this function is 0+0 instead of 3 + 4 according to the parameters I sent.
after some debugging I saw that it gets messed up in the createMoveTarget part but if i replace it with just right and left it throw an exception....
I also noticed that if I use t.newNumberLiteral to create 2 new lietrals and define the to be the value of what asgnThen.getRightHandSide and otherAsgn is the function returns a proper InfixExpression but the problem is it doesnt have to be a NumberLiteral so I cant count on that.
when the plugin lets me see the preview is shows "3 + " and no 0+0.... wierd stuff going on.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, needed to change the MoveTarget to CopyTarget.
I trie to "Move" the expression to 2 places in the conditional but "Move" here means actually moving it and not copying it which means I tried to move the same expression to 2 places but you only have 1 of him so you have to copy it with CopyTarget